# Expand footer DIV to bottom of window

Tags: css, xhtml

Is it possible to expand a footer DIV right down to the bottom of the window?

I have done the following:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 35px;
    background-color: #004467;
}
```

But this doesn't do what I want it to do. I need the footer to fill the available space right down to the bottom (with no gap before the previous DIV). Can anyone advise?

Comment: Could you post the CSS of the previous DIV as well?

Comment: The footer needs to expand in height, as well as stay at the bottom of the page.

Comment: check the solution I provided, it also covers height of the footer

Answer (score 2):

As per i understand you want `Sticky footer` technique. Check this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: The footer needs to expand in height, as well as stay at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this: http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-ie8new.htm